# Negation Outside of a parenthesis

Tags: logic

If a negation is outside the parenthesis like this, $\sim (p\wedge \sim q)$, does it negate the whole thing. I mean like how if you have like $3(5+3)$ do you like you distributive property or am I over thinking this.

Comment: Yes it does. The negation is a unary operator and a parenthesized expression is equivalent to one statement. If you want to take it inside (distribute it) you have to use De Morgan's Law. A simple example can be seen [here](http://www.ask-math.com/de-morgans-law.html).

Answer (score 2):

You have $\sim(P \wedge \sim Q) \iff \sim P \vee Q $
by DeMorgan's law.  The parens dictate the order of ops.

Comment: I'd have written $(\sim P)\vee Q$, just to make it clear that the $\sim$ applies only to the $P$.  Someone who asks this kind of question might not be clear about that, I would think.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\sim(A\wedge B\wedge C\wedge D\wedge\cdots) \text{ is equivalent to }(\sim A)\vee(\sim B)\vee(\sim C)\vee (\sim D)\vee\cdots
$$
$$
\sim(A\vee B\vee C\vee D\vee\cdots) \text{ is equivalent to }(\sim A)\wedge(\sim B)\wedge(\sim C)\wedge (\sim D)\wedge\cdots
$$
These are de Morgan's laws, named after Augustus de Morgan, a 19th-century Englishman.

You can see that these are true by using truth tables.

Sometimes one sees them applied to union and intersection of sets where instead of $\sim$ meaning logical negation, it means complementation, and they're still called de Morgan's laws then.

A similar thing applies to existential and universal quantifiers:
$$
\sim\exists x\ P\text{ is equivalent to } \forall x\ (\sim P)
$$
$$
\sim\forall x\ P\text{ is equivalent to }\exists x\ (\sim P)
$$